# Android ICS/JB, Reboot to Safe Mode Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am making a Utility app for my galaxy nexus. I want to reboot my tablet in safe mode.

I tried to look in `PowerManager`

```
PowerManager p = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
p.reboot(reason);
```

It seems this will not reboot the device in safe mode. Is it possible to reboot the device programmatically? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically there are two known ways to enter Safe Mode:
>
> 1. Android detects a problem with a newly installed app and force-closes it while entering into Safe Mode.
> 2. A combination of key presses at power application;

I doubt there's yet another way of doing it. If there was, most recoveries and power menus of Custom ROMS would have included that.

The string passed to `reboot()` is a kernel param, and would have effect only if device's kernel has that option. You can try some options here.

**UPDATE:**

Safe Mode is toggle is inside `PackageManagerService` of Android's system server ("package" service):

```
public void enterSafeMode() {
    enforceSystemOrRoot("Only the system can request entering safe mode");

    if (!mSystemReady) {
        mSafeMode = true;
    }
}
```

and here are some points about using it from any APP :

1. Process executing this code must be System or have Root previleges
2. This is an internal service and off-limits to any outside code. Though, some system classes indeed get implementation stubs (`IPackageManager`) of this service.
3. The mode change can only be useful when system is yet to be ready.
4. Let's suppose your app does turn on safe mode some how, due to safe mode being enabled, it won't be around to turn it off. Unless its a system app, built into ROM.

Comment: Hmmm. Seems there's no hope but I'm trying to explore the jelly bean source.

Answer (score 0):

A third way to enter safe mode (available sometime after GingerBread 2.3.5)

With device fully powered up, Press power  button, and the LONG press on the power off menu item.  An option appears to go into safe mode.  Because of this, there may now be a way to programmaticaly enter safe mode.  Sure hope so to help troubleshoot.  i am going from memory on a lifehacker article which referenced yet another source.